# Remove headers sent to server from the browser

Tags: php, apache, http-headers, sinemacula

### The Problem and My Question

I am currently trying to optimize a page on my site that returns a large amount of minified JavaScript.

By optimize, I mean speed up :-)

One of the ways I am trying to speed this page up is by reducing the headers sent to the server by the browser. 24 hours ago I would not have thought this to be possible, however, I have since then discovered a page that does just this and would like to know how and whether it is worth investigating further.

My page is located at https://libraries.sinemaculammviii.com/

The page I am comparing to is https://www.google.com/jsapi

**I have used http://tools.pingdom.com to test the speed of both of these pages, and one of the things that clearly shows is the lack of *request headers* that the Google page sends**

**How do they do this? Should I be doing it?**

**Does anyone have any other suggestions as to how I can speed up this page?**

I am currently using:

1. gzip to compress the page
2. JSPacker to minify the JavaScript
3. I will be applying caching headers (**I have not done this yet**)
4. Although this probably wont make a difference as the page is not static, I have routed my site through the CloudFlare CDN

### Evidence of the Solution

If you compare the headers (shown in the expanded results) in the following links, you can clearly see that there are no request headers sent by the Google page:

**[My Page](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/NY9ZnxDZ7/https://libraries.sinemaculammviii.com/)**

**[Google's Page](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/kIHgA861d/https://www.google.com/jsapi)**

**UPDATE 1**

I think I may have figured out the first step, or at least a possible first step. **Is it possible that Apache is just removing the headers?**

**UPDATE 2**

[image: My Page]

[image: Google's Page]

Comment: You have less response headers than google?

Comment: @Esailija Not the response headers, the request headers!! :-)

Comment: They are the same for me except for the parts such as cookie

Comment: I sort of assumed you cannot influence on headers sent FROM client. This is browser to decide what and how to do. I was wrong? If no - the results you see depend on analyze method applied on that website (http://tools.pingdom.com)

Comment: @Esailija are you looking at the links I posted to tools.pingdom.com? if you expand the results below, you can see that there are no *request headers* for the Google page, but for mine there are quite a few

Comment: @Serg Thats what I thought, but I cannot see how *tools.pingdom.com* could prevent the page from sending headers

Comment: @BenCarey Request headers mean headers sent by the browser, the browser doesn't look at a domain and say *nah, I won't send the accept-language header*, unless specifically configured. Response headers are the ones sent from the server which are the ones you can influence because you control the server.

Comment: @Esailija Exactly!!! So why are no *request headers* shown in the result on my page. I will post up an image to illustrate :-)

Comment: @BenCarey "request headers" shown on the pingdom page are not your browser's request headers but the headers sent by pingdom to the target server (or not even that, it's just random text on a webpage technically). I have no idea why they leave out the headers when sending requests to google though. To see what request headers your browser really sends, visit the page directly with packet sniffer or similar on.

Comment: @Esailija You have just stated exactly what I thought to be true. Glad it is not just me confused by this :-) Regardless of this, could this be one of the reasons that my page loads slower than the Google page?

Comment: @BenCarey It could be that your server is much slower, you have 5% of the time spent on receiving whereas with google that is 0.1%

Comment: @Esailija Yeah, I thought this might be the case, it would be weird as my server is not under any large load but anyway. I will leave this question open for others to answer, if you wish to answer yourself then please do and I will accept it, providing no one else manages to find an explanation :-)

Comment: Differences aside, I don't think that by leaving out headers you get any noticeable speed benefit. That's not the thing to focus on. For example, the way you have placed your script tags on your page has a lot more impact on the way page behaves for the end user.

Comment: @eis Yes that is true, but in a lot of cases you cannot place your script tags at the bottom of your HTML document. This is not relevant though as the document in question is a plain javascript page :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google speed does not come from the removal of headers, though I am sure this does not hurt.  The true speed comes from its modification of the Slow Start Algorithm.  For more information - go here: http://blog.benstrong.com/2010/11/google-and-microsoft-cheat-on-slow.html